# Remote line gap between items

Tags: lists

How to remote the line gap between the items?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mdwlist,lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=10mm, top=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm}
\begin{document}

\begin{basedescript}{\desclabelstyle{\pushlabel}\desclabelwidth{3cm}}
\item[Label 1] \lipsum[1]
\item[Label 2] \lipsum[1]
\end{basedescript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: MWE please : https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: `basedescript` .... where is this coming from?

Comment: Why aren't you using the more modern `enumitem` package?